# regex python pattern error

Tags: python, regex, hex

I am using the following regular expression pattern for searching in a text file :

- hexadecimal numbers (to find : 1a2bc3d4e5 or 2369.235.26.158963 or Aaa4 )
- only letters "a" or spaces. There may be "a", spaces or a mixture of
  two but nothing else. :

Below my regex for hexadecimal numbers :

```
matches = re.compile(' 0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+ ')
```

Below my regex for second pattern :

```
matches = re.compile(r'^[a| ]*$')
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Remove the spaces from the first RE. Also, your sample numbers (1a2b,..., etc) do not have a 0x at the start.

Comment: so i replace re.compile(' 0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+ ') by  re.compile('[0-9A-Fa-f]') : no match....

Comment: Please add an actual example of the data that does not match and the code that you use to match.

Comment: Please make it a part of your original question, not a comment.

Comment: i would like to find these datas :2369.235.26.158963 , Aaa4, AE456 , 1a2bc3d4e5f6, 1a2bc3d4e5f6g7 ,(0)1 52 69 78 56.My regex re.compile('[0-9A-Fa-f]') find nothing.Regards

Comment: First, 2369.235.26.158963 is _not_ a hex number. In fact, it is not a number at all. You must have a clear definition of whatever you want to find. Second, what function do you use to do the matching? `re.compile` does not match anything. It simply compiles a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, sometimes I think it's best when asking questions to include some of the actual input (or something close to it) and the desired output. For your hex numbers I'm wondering if you want to capture the 0x which precedes the value or avoid it; secondly variable length hex with your regex prototype (slightly corrected) would capture things like 'def', 'bad', etc. Anyway, having input and desired output helps with understanding the problem. The same can be said for people who answer.

With that said, for your first regex (cause I couldn't understand what you wanted for the second), I tend to prefer using "findall" cause it's more direct and yields group matching, so with the following input (presuming you know I'm creating a string in place of using the file.read() method and making my regex capture strings of more than 4 characters)

**Code**

```
import re

input = '''This is a hex number 0xAF67E49
This is NOT a hex number tgey736zde
This hex number 0xb34df49a appears in the middle of a sentence
This could be a hex number but has no letters 3689320'''

matches1 = re.findall('([0-9a-fA-F]{4,})', input)
matches2 = re.findall('0x([0-9a-fA-F]{4,})', input)
matches3 = re.findall('(0x[0-9a-fA-F]{4,})', input)

print('matches1: %s' % (str(matches1)))
print('matches2: %s' % (str(matches2)))
print('matches3: %s' % (str(matches3)))
```

**Output**

```
matches1: ['AF67E49', 'b34df49a', '3689320']
matches2: ['AF67E49', 'b34df49a']
matches3: ['0xAF67E49', '0xb34df49a']
```

**Explanation**

- matches1 indiscriminately matches anything that is 4 or more characters and falls within the hex range. Experiment with this by changing "tgey736zde" in the input to "tgey736de"
- matches2 effectively says capture any hex string of more than 4 characters preceded by 0x, ignoring the 0x
- matches3 effectively says capture any hex string of more than 4 characters preceded by 0x, but include the 0x

**Extra Information**

To make this more effective, you might want to research how to use lookaheads as well